# Set theory question on subsets (considering pairs)

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis

Consider some set $X$ with cardinality greater than or equal to $2$. If we consider that for a collection of subsets of $X$, denoted by $\{ M_{\alpha} \}$ consisting of at least one element for each $\alpha$, and for all $x,y \in X$, the pair $\{ x, y\} \subseteq M_{\alpha} \implies \{ x,y \} \not \subseteq M_{\beta}$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$. Moreover, we know that $\forall x \in M_{\alpha}$ we may find an $M_{\beta}$ such that $M_{\alpha} \cap M_{\beta} = \{ x \}$. We also have the condition that $X \neq M_{\alpha}$ for a single $\alpha$.

Is it true then that $\forall x \in X$, $x \in M_{\alpha}$ and $x \in M_{\beta}$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$? That is, $x$ is contained in at least two of these subsets.

Comment: Did you mean $\{ x, y\} \subseteq M_{\alpha}$ instead of $\{ x, y\} \in M_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Yes

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the set $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and the collection of subsets $M_\alpha$ as

$$
\{a,b\}~ \{b, c\} ~ \{c, a\}
$$

All the given conditions are satisfied, yet $d$ is not contained in any of the subsets.